# Programmatically merge & compress multiple video clips into one Video file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, video, video-processing

Looking for direction, guidance, examples. Are there solid video processing libraries to use? Javascript/Node and Ruby/Rails are my two platform options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do most of the stuff with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)
if you are looking for a good library to do it with node.js I can recommend [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg).

[Merging](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) (Concating)/Comperssing videos with ffmpeg should be pretty easy.